# Why the following set {max(f,g) < b} can be written as an intersection?

Tags: real-analysis

In one of the notes I have they say the following:

$$
\{max(f,g) < b\} = \{f < b\} \cap \{g < b \}
$$

and

$$
\{min(f,g) < b \} = \{f < b \} \cup \{g < b \}
$$

where $f,g$ are extended real-valued functions and b is a real number. I can't understand why these hold. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\{max(f,g)<b\}$. Let $f(x)\leq g(x)$ without loss of generality. Then $f(x)\leq g(x)<b$, thus both $f(x)<b$ and $g(x)<b$ hold. Hence $x$ lies in both $\{f(x)<b\}$ and $\{g(x)<b\}$.

As for the second, pick $x$ in $\{\min(f,g)<b\}$. Assume again that $f(x)\leq g(x)$. Then $f(x)<b$, hence $x$ lies in $\{f(x)<b\}$, hence in the union $\{f(x)<b\}\cup\{g(x)<b\}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\max(f(x),g(x))<b$ if and only if both $f(x)<b$ and $g(x)<b$, this easily follows from the definition of a maximum. Hence $x\in \{\max(f,g)<b\}$ iff $x$ is in both $\{f<b\}$ and  $\{g<b\}$, iff $x\in \{f<b\}\cap\{g<b\}$.

Similarly, $\min(f(x),g(x))<b$ if and only if $f(x)<b$ **or** $g(x)<b$.